# Buttons and pagination in datatables is showing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using to use [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) to display reports and records. But I am having an issue where the file export buttons and the pagination at the bottom are only showing as links not as buttons.

Here is a screenshot of my screen

[image]

This is what I have loaded in my page

```
<link href="/Vendor/bootstrap/v3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Vendor/bootstrap/v3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/JSZip/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Note, that I only want to use the datatable with bootstrap style.

Here is the code that I use to setup the datatable.

```
        $('#reportTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            columns: [
                { data: 'Category', title: 'Category' },
                { data: 'Svp', title: 'SVP' },
                { data: 'Rvp', title: 'RVP' },
                { data: 'Division', title: 'Division' },
                { data: 'ContactType', title: 'Contact Type' },
                { data: 'TotalRecords', title: 'Total Records' },

            ]

        });
```

What am I missing here? How can I fix this issue

UPDATED

I fixed the Export buttons but including the following file

```
Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js
```

The only open issue now is the pages at the bottom

Comment: Are you sure `bootstrap.css` is loaded?

Comment: Yes it is the first thing that is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js` script file include. If you downloaded these files from the official DataTables [download page](https://datatables.net/download/index) and the file path of the other files can be extrapolated to this one, I'd take a look and see if it exists here:

```
Vendor/datatables/v1.10.12/js/dataTables.boostrap.min.js
```

If it doesn't you may have to go back to the download page and make sure you get this script file.

Comment: I just figured it out and was about to post an answer but since you did I will accept your answer